# Redirect a webbrowser if chrome 18 is not found

Tags: url, href

I created this script to hide a page only if chrome 18 has not been found, how can I make sure to do the redirect of the url to a external page if chrome 18 has not been found instead of hiding only the page ?
I want to do the redirect to this website http://search.aol.com/aol/webhome

```html
<div id="hiddenContent" style="display: none;">
My hidden content.
</div>

<script>
function GetChromeVersion() {     
    var raw = navigator.userAgent.match(/Chrom(e|ium)\/([0-9]+)\./);
    return raw ? parseInt(raw[2], 10) : false;
}
if (GetChromeVersion() == 18)
    document.getElementById("hiddenContent").style.display = "";
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A page redirect if chrome 18 is not found (php html)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41845676/a-page-redirect-if-chrome-18-is-not-found-php-html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible, e.g. by using:

```
window.location.href='http://search.aol.com/aol/webhome';
```

Inside your function. BUT I wouldn't recommend you this. You should never trust the client as JavaScript can easily be changed and someone could access your site even despite the JavaScript redirect if they wanted to and made a minimal effort to modify page sources. Javascript is handled on the client-side, while php is completely server-side. In this case I'd use php instead of JavaScript. Try to check it with php and if it's not chrome 18, use: `header('Location: http://search.aol.com/aol/webhome');`

Edit:

`<?php function is_chrome()
{
return(eregi("chrome/18", $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])); }   if(is_chrome()) { header('Location: http://www.search.aol.com/aol/webhome'); } ?>`
Place it on top of the file, should work, but haven't tested it yet, if not, just change the string in eregi('chrome/18') to what you need (it's a regular expression)

Comment: Does not work means throwing error or just not redirecting? If it's not an error, but just doesn't redirect, first do: echo($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']); and it will print the user agent string on your webpage as text. Just read it and check if the eregi which searches for a regular expression matches the user agent string echoed. If not, correct it (I didn''t test it, so it's possible that the code doesn't check the string properly; I don't use chrome 18)

Comment: So just negate the if: if(!is_chrome()){...}

Comment: But now how do I add Chrome 46 with Chrome 18 togheter in the php code ?

Comment: function is_chrome() { return(eregi("chrome/18", $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) || eregi("chrome/46", $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])); }

Comment: No problem. Please consider marking the answer as correct by clicking the grey tick icon. This will give us both some reputation :-)